# How I can change position custom controls position google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have custom controls button, which open my filter. When the screen is changed custom controls button must other position.

I write that code

```
window.onresize = () => {
  if (screen.width <= 900) {
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].pop($controlsTabs);
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER].push($controlsTabs);
  }
}
```

And I get error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
```

This is because `$controlsTabs` does not have the position LEFT_TOP.

How to write the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

I decided problem

```
window.onresize = () => {
  if (screen.width <= 900) {
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].pop($controlsTabs);
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER].push($controlsTabs);
  } else {
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER].pop($controlsTabs); 
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push($controlsTabs);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', () => {
    google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, 'resize');
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.